# Rails Model has_many with multiple foreign_keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, has-many

Relatively new to rails and trying to model a very simple family "tree" with a single Person model that has a name, gender, father_id and mother_id (2 parents). Below is basically what I want to do, but obviously I can't repeat the :children in a has_many (the first gets overwritten).

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :father, :class_name => 'Person'
  belongs_to :mother, :class_name => 'Person'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'mother_id'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'father_id'
end
```

Is there a simple way to use has_many with 2 foreign keys, or maybe change the foreign key based on the object's gender? Or is there another/better way altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: For Rails 3, scope chainning, ActiveRecord::Relation and eventually `has_many`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476521/rails-has-many-custom-activerecord-association/17476639#17476639

Comment: You are looking for "composit keys": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882105/is-it-possible-to-define-composite-primary-key-for-table-using-active-record

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Found a simple answer on IRC that seems to work (thanks to Radar):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :father, :class_name => 'Person'
  belongs_to :mother, :class_name => 'Person'
  has_many :children_of_father, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'father_id'
  has_many :children_of_mother, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'mother_id'
  def children
     children_of_mother + children_of_father
  end
end
```

Comment: If there are any default scopes, in particular, those which might affect the order of the results, this solution will not work as the results will not be ordered as expected.

Comment: you can get an `ActiveRecord:Relation` by defining #children like I did in my answer below

Comment: Wouldn't this fire off two SQL queries? If you wanted to add more relations, this could get pretty inefficient.

Comment: WARNING: With Rails 4.2 (and probably everything before this), calling `children` triggers two SQL requests (one for `children_of_father` and one for `children_of_mother`). With large a large data set, that won't be efficient. @stefvhuynh, thank you for raising the point.

Answer (score 17):

To improve on [Kenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13636/kenzie)'s answer, you can achieve an ActiveRecord Relation by defining `Person#children` like:

```
def children
   children_of_mother.merge(children_of_father)
end
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9540911) for more details

Comment: WARNING: As explained in the answer you mention, relations are merged with an `AND`. Which doesn't work with this example, because it means you select only people who have `mother_id` *and* (instead of *or*) `father_id` set to the id of the target. I'm not a doctor but it shouldn't happen that often :)

Comment: .merge worked in my case where I needed AND. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Used named_scopes over the Person model
do this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

    def children
      Person.with_parent(id)
    end

    named_scope :with_parent, lambda{ |pid| 

       { :conditions=>["father_id = ? or mother_id=?", pid, pid]}
    }
 end
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe you can achieve the relationships you want using :has_one.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :father, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'father_id'
  has_one :mother, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'mother_id'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Person'
end
```

I'll confirm and edit this answer after work ; )

Comment: This didn't work for me... seemed to good to be true, but I got the expected erorr for the `has_many` relationship: 'no column named `person_id` in table `people`.

Answer (score 5):

My answer to [Associations and (multiple) foreign keys in rails (3.2) : how to describe them in the model, and write up migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40427001/5678119) is just for you!

As for your code,here are my modifications

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :father, :class_name => 'Person'
  belongs_to :mother, :class_name => 'Person'
  has_many :children, ->(person) { unscope(where: :person_id).where("father_id = ? OR mother_id = ?", person.id, person.id) }, class_name: 'Person'
end
```

So any questions?

Comment: This is awesome!  There are several incorrect answers to the question on StackOverflow, but this works perfectly.  Quick correction though: you misspelled `mother_id`.

Comment: @KalleSamuelsson thanks for you support! Love your comment!

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use scopes for this issue. Like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :father, :class_name => 'Person'
  belongs_to :mother, :class_name => 'Person'
  has_many :children_of_father, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'father_id'
  has_many :children_of_mother, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'mother_id'

  scope :children_for, lambda {|father_id, mother_id| where('father_id = ? AND mother_id = ?', father_id, mother_id) }
end
```

This trick make it easy to get children without use instances:

```
Person.children_for father_id, mother_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution to the general question as stated ("has_many with multiple foreign keys"), but, given a person can either be a mother or a father, but not both, I would add a `gender` column and go with

```
  has_many :children_of_father, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'father_id'
  has_many :children_of_mother, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'mother_id'
  def children
    gender == "male" ? children_of_father : children_of_mother
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same feature, if you don't want to return an array but a `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation`, you can use `<<` instead of `+`.
([See the ActiveRecord documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-3C-3C))

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :father, :class_name => 'Person'
  belongs_to :mother, :class_name => 'Person'

  has_many :children_of_father, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'father_id'
  has_many :children_of_mother, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => 'mother_id'

  def children
     children_of_mother << children_of_father
  end
end
```

Comment: The shovel operator (<<) would actually update database records, not just cause a union in the result set. Children of the father would now also be children of the mother.