# form drop down select relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am confused with this. I have a company model and a message model. Company has_many messages and messages belongs_to company. I am having problems with the data being saved to the proper company with this form is saved.

```
<%= form_for(@msg) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'errors', :object => f.object %>
    <ul class="fields">
      <li> 
        <%= select("msg", "company_id", Company.all.collect {|p| [ p.title, p.id ] }) %>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="fields">
      <li><%= f.label :content, "Send this company your message" %></li>
      <li><%= f.text_area :content %></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Send" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

every time this form is saved the company_id is null. My code for the controller to save is

```
def create
  @msg = current_user.messages.build(params[:msg])
  if @msg.save
    flash[:success] = "New message saved"
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    render current_user
  end
end
```

Nothing stands out to me as to why this is not saving, can someone guide me to the right direction?

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, don't you need to find the current company?  Something like

```
@company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
@message = @Company.messages.create(params[:msg])
```

would work.  As far as mixing has_many with both users and companies, this thread on SO seems good. [Rails Model has_many with multiple foreign_keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307581/rails-model-has-many-with-multiple-foreign-keys)