# How should this model be designed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In a Rails app, I want to allow users to send messages from one to another. So, I have a User model that will have this:

```
has_many :messages
```

I was thinking that the `Message` model will have a `from` field, containing the id of the user that sent it, and a `to` field, containing the user id of the user that it's addressed to. What would be the best practice for the Messsage model? Should I generate it like this:

`rails g model Message from:integer to:integer title:string content:text`

How would I associate it to a user? Should I associate it to 2 users, since the `from` and `to` fields reference existing users? How would I represent this relationship? What kind of relationship would I write in the message model? `belongs_to :user` ?

I feel there should be a way of letting Rails manage the user id's for me, so that I don't have to create integer fields myself.

Comment: Just as a heads up: `send` is a metaprogramming method in Ruby, so you may want to avoid using that word if practical.

Comment: Hey Andrew! I know, but I think that in the context of exchanging messages, using `send` doesn't suggest any metaprogramming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
User

has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => 'from'
has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => 'to'

Message

belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'from'
belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'User' :foreign_key => 'to'
```

Comment: I would actually name the columns from_id and to_id, but this is how I would program it.

Comment: Yes, that is the standard way

Comment: Thank you Ashish, this works very nice. Can you show me please to what kind of database calls these would translate to? I'd like to fully understand this.

Comment: Assuming that `sent_messages` and `received_messages` are symbols, there shouldn't be a space between the colon and the word.

Answer (score 2):

If you want both you should probably do something like this

```
has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'from'
has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'to'
```

This is similar to this question: [Rails Model has_many with multiple foreign_keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307581/rails-model-has-many-with-multiple-foreign-keys)

Comment: So I'd have to generate my model like I wrote in my post?