# Union of two active record relations should be another active record in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need get union of two `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects in such a way that the resultant should be another active record relation. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: ' union of two active records ' mean?

Comment: I have two active records for same model but with different records. I want to combine both of those active records and the result should be another active record. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You've got to give some code to go off of, otherwise people have no idea how to help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine two ActiveRecord::Relation objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540801/combine-two-activerecordrelation-objects)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update for Rails 5**

`ActiveRecord` now brings built-in support for `UNION`/`OR` queries! Now you can (the following examples are taken, as-is, from [this nice post](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/30/rails-5-adds-or-support-in-active-record.html). Make sure you read the full post for more tricks and limitations):

```
Post.where(id: 1).or(Post.where(title: 'Learn Rails'))
```

or combine with `having`:

```
posts.having('id > 3').or(posts.having('title like "Hi%"'))
```

or even mix with scopes:

```
Post.contains_blog_keyword.or(Post.where('id > 3'))
```

**Original answer follows**

I do not think that AR provides a union method. You can either execute raw SQL and use SQL's UNION or perform the 2 different queries and union the results in Rails.

Alternatively you could take a look in these custom "hacks": 
[ActiveRecord Query Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686920/activerecord-query-union) or 
https://coderwall.com/p/9hohaa

Comment: @rkon could you please provide an example of how to "union the results in Rails"? Thanks.

Comment: He means `ruby`, union the two arrays in `ruby` with the union operator `|`

Comment: Right @Volte, or just use the convenient `+` defined on `ActiveRecord::Relation`