# Scoping an Array of the same class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, named-scope

I have two models `Board` and `Pictures` and I want a user to be able to comment on either the `Board` as a whole or the individual `Pictures`.

My polymorphic Comment model:

```
 class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
 end
```

and then I have a simple `has_many` in each of the other models:

```
 class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
     has_many :pictures

 class Pictures < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
     belongs_to :board
```

What I really want to be able to do is add a new scope called something like `all_comments` which combines the comments from the `Board` model with the related comments from the `Pictures` model.  I can do this with a method, but I end up with an array and not a scoped relation.

My method:

```
def all_comments
    comments = self.comments
    return comments + self.pictures.map {|x| x.comments}.flatten
end
```

How can I return a scoped relationship that can chain the results?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540801/combine-two-activerecordrelation-objects

Comment: @DamienRoche you need to create a proper scope for your proposed solution, won't work with the map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all Pictures should be singular.

secondly, you can just call a finder on Comment to get all the comments you want

`Comment.where("type = 'board' AND id IN(?) OR type = 'picture' AND id IN(?)", self.id, self.pictures.map(&:id))`

or something like that.

Comment: simplicity is always the answer.  cant believe I didnt think of this!  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`phoet`'s answer intrigued me (I +1'd), so here's my refactor / expansion on what he suggested:

---

You'd look in the `Comment` model to pull out the relevant comments. To do this, you need to firstly know the board & the pictures associated with it. Phoet uses the `self.pictures` object for this:

```
#app/models/comment.rb
Class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
    def all_comments
        ids = self.id + self.pictures.map(&:id)
        Comment.find(ids)
    end
end
```

This will find the ids in the `comment` model, returning the data as a collection. If you wanted a true representation of the comments (hierarchical), you'd have to use some sort of `ancestry` / `inheritance` structure I think

Comment: No this wouldnt work, but interesting try.  It would match IDs from other models that are also using the Comments model.