# Is there a way to combine relations with OR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

What the question says, Is it possible to merge two relations in an `OR` fashion instead of resolving and adding as arrays?

I want to avoid resolving to arrays but would be nice to have the syntax shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15236011/1520364, i.e `a + b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support for OR has been merged about 8 days ago, so if you use the HEAD version you can use it like:

```
Post.where('id = 1').or(Post.where('id = 2'))

# => SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (id = 1) OR (id = 2)
```

You can the the merged pull request [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9e42cf019f2417473e7dcbfcb885709fa2709f89)

Comment: Oh wow! hot off the presses indeed.. is this headed for v 5? Or 4.2.x?

Comment: @KarthikT I believe it will be on 5.x according to https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/version.rb