# Active Record query for has_many/belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have built a Rails app that has data about the US Congress.  I have a Legislator model and a Bill model:

```
class Legislator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bills
end

class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :legislator
end
```

So bills that a legislator has sponsored are tied to that legislator.  The legislator also has a "party" attribute that is either "R", "D", or "I"

I want to get a list of all bills that were sponsored by all legislators from a particular party, e.g., all bills that were sponsored by Democrat.  What would this query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join and put the query as a hash

```
Bill.joins(:legislator).where(legislators: {party: 'D'})
```

Comment: This is giving me an error ` from bin/rails:12:in `<main>'irb(main):025:0> Bill.joins(:legislator).where(legislator: {party: 'D'})
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "legislator"
LINE 1: ...lators"."id" = "bills"."legislator_id" WHERE "legislato...`
                                                             ^

Comment: ok I think because i need to say `legislators: {party: 'D'}` instead of `legislator: {party: 'D'}` ( the missing `s` )

Answer (score 2):

```
Bill.joins(:legislator).where(legislators: {party: "I"})
```

But I would advise you to write scopes on Legislator and Bill

```
# class Legislator
scope :by_party, ->(party) do
  where(party: party)
end

# class Bill
scope :sponsored_by_party, ->(party) do
  joins(:legislator).merge(Legislator.by_party(party))
end
```

Then you can write

```
Bill.sponsored_by_party("I")
```

Comment: what's the query generated when you do that joins + merge ?

Comment: Since I'm not at a console, I have to fake it. It should be `SELECT bills.* FROM bills INNER JOIN legislators ON legislators.id = bills.legislator_id WHERE legislators.party = 'I';`

Comment: so active record supports a `.merge` method on the relation level correct? cause i thought it would be some array merging, i'll need to read about this, thanks +1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9540801/597358 and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge