# ActiveRecord .merge not working on two relations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models in my app:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gallery_cards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :photos, through: :gallery_cards
  has_many :direct_photos, class_name: 'Photo'
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery_card
  belongs_to :company
end

class GalleryCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :photos
end
```

As you can see, `Company` `has_many :photos, through: :gallery_cards` and also `has_many :photos`. `Photo` has both a `gallery_card_id` and a `company_id` column.

What I want to be able to do is write a query like `@company.photos` that returns an ActiveRecord::Relation of all the company's photos. In my `Company` model, I currently have the method below, but that returns an array or ActiveRecord objects, rather than a relation.

```
def all_photos
   photos + direct_photos
end
```

I've tried using the `.merge()` method (see below), but that returns an empty relation. I think the reason is because the conditions that are used to select `@company.photos` and `@company.direct_photos` are different. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9540911/4139179) explains it in more detail.

```
@company = Company.find(params[:id])
photos = @company.photos
direct_photos = @company.direct_photos
direct_photos.merge(photos) = []
photos.merge(direct_photos) = []
```

I've also tried numerous combinations of `.joins` and `.includes` without success.

this might be a candidate for a raw SQL query, but my SQL skills are rather basic.

For what it's worth, I revisited this and came up (with help) another query that grabs everything in one shot, rather than building an array of ids for a second query. This also includes the other join tables:

```
Photo.joins("
   LEFT OUTER JOIN companies ON photos.company_id = #{id}
   LEFT OUTER JOIN gallery_cards ON gallery_cards.id = photos.gallery_card_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN quote_cards ON quote_cards.id = photos.quote_card_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN team_cards ON team_cards.id = photos.team_card_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN who_cards ON who_cards.id = photos.who_card_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN wild_cards ON wild_cards.id = photos.wild_card_id"
   ).where("photos.company_id = #{id}
       OR gallery_cards.company_id = #{id}
       OR quote_cards.company_id = #{id}
       OR team_cards.company_id = #{id}
       OR who_cards.company_id = #{id}
       OR wild_cards.company_id = #{id}").uniq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord's [`merge`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) returns the *intersection* not the union of the two queries – counterintuitively IMO.

To find the union, you need to use `OR`, for which ActiveRecord has poor built-in support. So I think you're correct that its best to write the conditions in SQL:

```
def all_photos
  Photo.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN gallery_cards ON gallery_cards.id = photos.gallery_card_id")
    .where("photos.company_id = :id OR gallery_cards.company_id = :id", id: id)
end
```

**ETA** The query associates the `gallery_cards` to `photos` with a [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), which preserves those photo rows without associated gallery card rows. You can then query based on either `photos` columns or on associated `gallery_cards` columns – in this case, `company_id` from either table.

You can leverage ActiveRecord scope chaining to join and query from additional tables:

```
def all_photos
  Photo.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN gallery_cards ON gallery_cards.id = photos.gallery_card_id")
    .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN quote_cards ON quote_cards.id = photos.quote_card_id")
    .where("photos.company_id = :id OR gallery_cards.company_id = :id OR quote_cards.company_id = :id", id: id)
end
```

Comment: I agree, the name is very counterintuitive. I tried your query but I'm getting an error: `PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "company_id" is ambiguous LINE 1: ... gallery_cards.id = photos.gallery_card_id WHERE (company_id...`

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. I just needed to prepend `photos` to `company_id` in the WHERE clause. Thanks!

Comment: How can I expand the query if Company has_many Photos through multiple join tables (gallery_cards, quote_cards, etc)?

Comment: Thanks again! I edited my original post with the final query I ended up using. I got it working before by running several queries to build an array of ids, which got passed to a final query, but it was pretty lousy code.