# Combine two where queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, public-activity

How do I merge these two ActiveRecord Relations?

```
activity1 = PublicActivity::Activity.where("user_recipients LIKE ':id,%' or user_recipients LIKE '%, :id' or user_recipients LIKE '%, :id,%' or user_recipients = ':id'", id: current_user.id)

activity2 = PublicActivity::Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id, recipient_type: 'User')
```

When I do this, if one is empty they default to the empty one

```
@activity = activity1.merge(activity2)
```

Comment: You mean chaining the `where` queries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two ActiveRecord::Relation objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540801/combine-two-activerecordrelation-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple why the merge is return empty array it's because it use `AND` between the queries try this:

```
@activity = (activity1 + activity2)
```