# How to run this expression in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, functional-programming

I have two models

```
class Filters < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Groups < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Filter model is responsible for fetching user data from db e.g

filter_id_1. `SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN notes ON notes.user_id = users.id WHERE notes.category = 'Emotions'`

filter_id_2. `SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.user_id = users.id WHERE (Date(end_date) = CURDATE())`

filter_id_3. `SELECT users.* FROM users  WHERE (auth_token_created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 hour))`

Group model makes a group with multiple filters with AND and OR conditions e.g

group_id_1 = `"filter_id_1 AND filter_id_2 OR filter_id_3"`

Now using group I am trying to fetch users by converting expression to methods according to AND OR conditions.

```
users = Filter.find(1).get_users &  Filter.find(2).get_users | Filter.find(3).get_users
```

How can i convert this experssion from this `"filter_id_1 AND filter_id_2 OR filter_id_3"`

to this

`users = Filter.find(1).get_users &  Filter.find(2).get_users | Filter.find(3).get_users`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, you might want to convert your group format to something more structured, like `[1, '&', 2, '|', 3]`, which will make it easier to apply. If not, we can get there pretty quickly with some simple substitutions:

```
parts = 'filter_id_1 AND filter_id_2 OR filter_id_3'
  .gsub('filter_id_', '')
  .gsub('AND', '&')
  .gsub('OR', '|')
  .split
#=> ["1", "&", "2", "|", "3"]
```

Then you can construct your list of users by walking through the symbols:

```
parts = ["1", "&", "2", "|", "3"]
users = Filter.find(parts.shift).get_users
while parts.any?
  op = parts.shift
  next_users = Filter.find(parts.shift).get_users
  users = users.send(op, next_users)
end
```

As long as there's something left in `parts` (and assuming the group was well formed), you know there's an operation followed by another filter ID. Grabbing each of those, you can send the `op` to your existing `users` to apply the next set of users in the right way.

Comment: Thanks that very genius. It totally solves the purpose

Answer (score 0):

A better solution for your purpose I think is that **using scope in User model and query methods**.

### Query Methods

In rails, ActiveRecord offers lots of query methods to implement that, like this:

```
User.joins(:notes).where(notes: {category: 'Emotions'})
```

This produces:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN notes ON notes.user_id = users.id WHERE notes.category = 'Emotions'
```

ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

### Scope

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User
  scope :group_by_note_category -> (category){
    self.joins(:notes).where(notes: {category: category})
  }
end

#use like this
User.group_by_note_category('Emotions')
```

Your purpose is that combine two Active:Relation objects using 'And' and 'Or'. Hoping this would be of use.

ref: [Combine two ActiveRecord::Relation objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540801/combine-two-activerecordrelation-objects)

Comment: I agree with you ActiveRecord Query would be an awesome solution. But Scopes can be used when you know what exact relation you have to define b/w filters. These filters will be generated on the fly by users. 
It could be any thing like: "filter_1 AND filter_2" or lets say "filter_2 AND filter_4 AND filter_6".  here I dont know user will define what exact combination b/w filters.