# How to use association inside rails partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Task model:

```
## Task
has_many :children, :class_name => "Task"
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Task", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
```

Basically user has many tasks and each task has many child tasks.

I did this inside a view:

```
<%= render @tasks %>
```

And it used to work fine when the data structure was one dimensional.

However I keep getting the error message "(SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tasks.task_id: SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks"  WHERE "tasks"."task_id" = 138)" after adding the associations. I was expecting "parent_id", since that's what the model is supposed to refer to.

I am guessing that this is because of how rails implicitly connects the local variable "task" with its class "task". For example, I want to build a form inside comment like so:

```
## inside _task.html.erb
<%= form_for task.children.build do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
<% end %>
```

But it doesn't work because task.children gets an error saying that task doesn't have a column "task_id", when it's supposed to refer to "parent_id". Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> foreign_key
>
> Specify the foreign key used for the association. By
> default this is guessed to be the name of the association with an
> “_id” suffix. So a class that defines a belongs_to :person association
> will use “person_id” as the default :foreign_key. Similarly,
> belongs_to :favorite_person, :class_name => "Person" will use a
> foreign key of “favorite_person_id”.

```
belongs_to :children, :class_name => "Task",:foreign_key => "parent_id"
```

You may want to use pk, Im not sure about the table structure.

Also, you may want to have a table many-to-many even if it is one way (one-to-many) for cleaner data.  It will depend on the processes you need\use.

Comment: I don't understand the answer. Are you saying I should model the association as parent and child pointing each other with belongs_to, and no has_many? As I wrote above, I already have :foreign_key => "parent_id" in my belongs_to :parent association. Also I don't understand why you're suggesting I model this as belongs_to :children instead of has_many :children.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild your association.

```
has_many :children, :class_name => "Task", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Task"
```

Because below question proved that there is mistake in Rails documentation.

[Ruby on Rails guides document on Activerecord association incorrect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835239/ruby-on-rails-guides-document-on-activerecord-association-incorrect)

For your reference visit below question and see how the associations are used in this answer.

[Rails Model has_many with multiple foreign_keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307581/rails-model-has-many-with-multiple-foreign-keys)