# Ruby on Rails guides document on Activerecord association incorrect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Wow I've been struggling with this for whole day, following the "official" ruby on rails guides document, and just discovered that I might have been misguided by the document all along. I just want to confirm if this is true.

If you go to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and under 2.10. self joins section it says:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subordinates, :class_name => "Employee"
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "Employee",
    :foreign_key => "manager_id"
end
```

Now, I'm a newbie and just believed in this code (What else can I do?) and wrote some code that's a variation of this self join case. However the more I looked at it the more it didn't feel right. isn't `:subordinates` supposed to have the `:foreign_key` field instead of `:manager`? Anyway I've just changed it so that the code is something like:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subordinates, :class_name => "Employee", :foreign_key => "manager_id"
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "Employee"
end
```

and now it's working. Am I missing something? Or is the official document wrong? It's hard to believe that the official document would present incorrect information but maybe that's the way it is.

Comment: Yes, you're right. An association named `manager` would of course correctly assume the foreign key `manager_id`. And then the `subordinates` association would the same way assume the invalid foreign_key `subordinate_id` so that is the one that needs changing.

Comment: I send commit to docrails, that fixes this error

Comment: I see how the :foreign_key=>'manager_id' was correctly placed.As far as I know the foreign_key goes with the belongs_to side of the relation.I would like to see an example of what you call "...and now it's working".Of course I could be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, [the guide document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) is incorrect at the time of this writing.

The `belongs_to` doesn't need the `:foreign_key` option because AR will infer `manager_id` from the name of the association ("manager"). As documented, AR would raise an error when, given an Employee `@dwight` one attempts to `@dwight.subordinates`, because AR would use `employee_id` in the WHERE condition of the SELECT statement.

According to the [AR documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) passing the `:foreign_key` option to `has_many` results in declaring the FK that will be used when generating the query for `@dwight.subordinates`.