# Last with a custom column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have my model defined like this:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

    attr_accessible :picture, :born_date, :father_id, :mother_id, :name, :obs, :earring, :animal_type, :animal_type_id, :inseminations

    validates :name, :born_date, :presence => true
    validates :earring, :presence => true, :if => :should_have_earring?

    belongs_to :father, :class_name => "Animal"
    belongs_to :mother, :class_name => "Animal"
    belongs_to :animal_type
    has_one :birth

    has_one :sell
    has_one :death

    has_many :inseminations
end
```

and

```
class Insemination < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bull_id, :cow_id, :done, :expected_birth_date, :expected_dry_date, :insemination_date, :obs, :rut

  validates :bull_id, :presence => true
  validates :cow_id, :presence => true
  validates :insemination_date, :presence => true

  belongs_to :bull, :class_name => "Animal"
  belongs_to :cow, :class_name => "Animal"

  has_one :birth
  has_one :abortion
  has_one :dry
end
```

Good, somewhere, I want to get the last insemination from some animal... so, I do `@animal.inseminations.last`, it should work, but, it does the select using a `animal_id` property, that does not exist in insemination model. So I get an error like this:

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'inseminations.animal_id' in 'where
>   clause': SELECT  `inseminations`.* FROM `inseminations`  WHERE
>   `inseminations`.`animal_id` = 1 ORDER BY `inseminations`.`id` DESC
>   LIMIT 1

How can I specify it to searh in `cow_id` and/or `bull_id` columns? Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried using instances of Bull and Cow? Like `@bull = Bull.first`, `@bull.inseminations.last`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a few different options:

1) Instead of using `has_many :inseminations`, create two separate has many relationships:

```
has_many :cow_inseminations, :class_name => 'Insemination', :foreign_key => 'cow_id'
has_many :bull_inseminations, :class_name => 'Insemination', :foreign_key => 'bull_id'
```

2) Use STI and create subclasses of Animal. You will need to add a type field to Animal for this to work:

```
class Cow < Animal
  has_many :inseminations, :foreign_key => 'cow_id'
end

class Bull < Animal
  has_many :inseminations, :foreign_key => 'bull_id'
end
```

Then you can do Bull.first.inseminations or Cow.first.inseminations

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a foreign key:

```
has_many :inseminations, :foreign_key => :bull_id
```

However you can only have one foreign_key, so it doesn't work for the cows.

You can do something like [Rails Model has_many with multiple foreign_keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307581/rails-model-has-many-with-multiple-foreign-keys) to get it to work. But then in this case, you need:

```
has_many :bull_inseminations, :foreign_key => :bull_id
has_many :cow_inseminations, :foreign_key => :cow_id

def inseminations
  # not sure how you store animal type, but something like
  return bull_inseminations if animal_type == "bull"
  return cow_inseminations if animal_type == "cow"
end
```

For other attribute methods, you will need to do something similar if you want to use them, eg:

```
def inseminations_changed?
  bull_inseminations_changed? or cow_inseminations_changed?
end
```

and similarly with inseminations<<, inseminations=, etc.

Comment: thanks... I tested the Beerlington first, because it's look more simpler, but I do believe that your should work too. Thanks.