# What type of model relationship should I use for two foreign key references in same row?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create an `Event` model that has two references to the `Contact` model.

Why two? Because a `Contact` can either be of type `Client` or `Organizer`.

How can I add two foreign key columns to my `Event` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients, :class_name => 'Contact', :foreign_key => 'client_id'
  has_many :organizers, :class_name => 'Contact', :foreign_key => 'organizer_id'
end
```

source: [Rails Model has_many with multiple foreign_keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307581/rails-model-has-many-with-multiple-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the solution you are looking for but I think using "[Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)" in this case would be suitable.

So, your `Contact` model will be the polymorphic association model, which will hold either `Client` or `Organizer` per row.

Association between these models would then be:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :event
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
end

class Organizer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
end
```

The migration for this model would then be:

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.references :contactable, polymorphic: true

      # Other contacts attributes
    end
  end
end
```